# find total amount of a customer in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

i'm trying to find out the total amount of a particular customer in an inventory database.
the tables are : 
customer, tax, invoice, line_no, branch, items, employee

i was able to calculate the total but i get multiple amounts as it calculates the amount for each tax rate in the database. i'm trying to restrict the amount depending on the branch issues it. i hope i made it clear, here is the query:

```
SELECT  ROUND((SUM((LINE_NO.RETAIL_PRICE - LINE_NO.DISCOUNT)* LINE_NO.DEL_QTY)* (TAX.TAX_RATE))+
SUM((LINE_NO.RETAIL_PRICE - LINE_NO.DISCOUNT)* LINE_NO.DEL_QTY),2)
AS "TOTAL PAYMENT" 
FROM LINE_NO, TAX, BRANCH
WHERE LINE_NO.INVOICE_INVOICE_NO IN (SELECT INVOICE.INVOICE_NO from INVOICE
WHERE(INVOICE.CUSTOMER_CUST_NO IN (SELECT CUST_NO from CUSTOMER where CUSTOMER.FNAME='JIM' ))) 
AND TAX.CITY = BRANCH.CITY
GROUP BY TAX.TAX_RATE;
```

Comment: I understand you don't want a result for each tax rate, but then there must be some condition that specifies which tax rate is applicable. Do you know whether one of the records relates to one specific rate?

Comment: exactly. yes the rate can be retrieved from the branch location, which can be tracked by the Invoice number. so i added another query after 'AND TAX.CITY = BRANCH.CITY' which helped to determine the tax rate i'm looking for and got it working, thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

GROUP BY should not operate on TAX_RATE here to avoid calculate total amount for each group (TAX_RATE).

```
SELECT  ROUND((SUM((LINE_NO.RETAIL_PRICE - LINE_NO.DISCOUNT)* LINE_NO.DEL_QTY)* (TAX.TAX_RATE))+
SUM((LINE_NO.RETAIL_PRICE - LINE_NO.DISCOUNT)* LINE_NO.DEL_QTY),2)
AS "TOTAL PAYMENT" 
FROM LINE_NO, TAX, BRANCH
WHERE LINE_NO.INVOICE_INVOICE_NO IN (SELECT INVOICE.INVOICE_NO from INVOICE
WHERE(INVOICE.CUSTOMER_CUST_NO IN (SELECT CUST_NO from CUSTOMER where CUSTOMER.FNAME='JIM' ))) 
AND TAX.CITY = BRANCH.CITY;
```

Comment: that did not work but never mind i figured it out thanks

Answer (score 0):

exactly. yes the rate can be retrieved from the branch location, which can be tracked by the Invoice number. so i added another query after:

```
AND TAX.CITY = BRANCH.CITY
```

which helped to determine the tax rate i'm looking for and got it working, thanks anyways